# cannot view newly created delta table via DeltaTable.forPath

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, databricks-connect

I created a table like this and inserted some data

```
spark.sql(s"create table if not exists test " +
"(key String," +
"name String," +
"address String," +
"inserted_at TIMESTAMP) " +
s"  using delta  LOCATION 's3://test/user/'")
```

I can view the table via

```
spark.table("test").show()
```

But when I do

```
DeltaTable.forPath(spark,"s3://test/user/" ).toDF.show(false)
```

I cannot see the data. But when i try this method

```
DeltaTable.isDeltaTable("s3://test/user/")
```

it is true. Can anyone please explain what I am missing?

Further, when I want to do a merge operation, I am getting this error.

```
[error] ! 
[error]  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null (DeltaTable.scala:639)
[error] io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$.forPath(DeltaTable.scala:639)
```

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/85#issuecomment-602080559) it sounds related. In general it is unclear how is the Delta metadata managed in different environments i.e on-premise vs databricks